# Create a new column in multiple dataframes using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes with the same structure but different values
for instance,

```
df0, df1, df2...., df9
```

To each dataframe I want to add a column named `eventdate` that consists of one date, for instance, `2019-09-15` using for loop

```
for i in range(0, 9);
    df+str(i)['eventdate'] = "2021-09-15"
```

but I get an error message
`SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator`

I think it's because `df` isn't defined. This should be very simple.. Any idea how to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
dfs = [df0, df1, df2...., df9]
dfs_new = []

for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df['eventdate'] = "2021-09-15"
    dfs_new.append(df)
```

if you can't generate a list then you could use `eval(f"df{str(num)}")` but this method isn't recommended from what I've seen

Comment: I do not want to upend dfs.. I just want to have them separate but add a column to each df? in this case, should I just remove the last line of command?

Comment: so then you'll want to use the eval() method. you can assign the df as a tmp variable, add the column, then overwrite the original variable